# IntelliJ Idea not detecting SWC classes in a Haxe project

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, haxe

I'm trying to set up a new project in IntelliJ Idea, it's a Haxe project and I've added a SWC as a dependency. However, I can't use any of the classes from this SWC as it says it cannot find the class.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I think you can generate externs for your SWC, and add it to classpaths, might work
http://old.haxe.org/manual/swc#hx-classes-generation